# How can we convert azure maps language when user clicks on map using js or ts?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am declaring a click event for azure maps in angular 6, So If map is clicked in dubai location I am getting arabic text I want to convert into English language.

Here is my code :

```js
 mapClicked(e) {
    console.log(e);
    OrderOnlineComponent.searchURL.searchAddressReverse(atlas.service.Aborter.timeout(30000), e.position).then(results => {
      let data = results.geojson.getFeatures();
      console.log(data);
      let content = '<div style="padding:10px">';
      if (data.features.length > 0 && data.features[0].properties && data.features[0].properties.address && data.features[0].properties.address.freeformAddress) {
        content += data.features[0].properties.address.freeformAddress;
      } else {
        content += 'No address for that location!';
      }
      content += '</div>';
      //Set the popup options.
      // console.log("content to display...:", data.features[0].properties.address.freeformAddress.split(','));
      // this.setVal(data.features[0].properties.address.freeformAddress.split(','));
      OrderOnlineComponent.popup.setOptions({
        position: e.position,
        content: content
      });

      OrderOnlineComponent.addressObserve.next(data.features[0].properties.address.freeformAddress.split(','));
      //Open the popup.
      OrderOnlineComponent.popup.open(OrderOnlineComponent.etAddMap);
      // return (data.features[0].properties.address.freeformAddress);
    });
  }
```

Any help in this ?

Comment: I found the solution Hope it would help others
  AddEditComponent.searchURL.searchAddressReverse(atlas.service.Aborter.timeout(30000), e.position,{
      view:'Auto',
      language:'en-Us'
    }).then(results => {